# Python unittest class issue

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to write a unit test class in python but feel like I'm missing something fundamental as it's not doing what I would expect. Here is my class:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class MyTestClass(TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = None

    def setUp(self):

        self.file_name = 'give this file a name'

        return self.file_name

    def test_a_file_name(self):

        assert self.file_name == 'give this file a name', 'fail'


tester = MyTestClass()
tester.setUp()
tester.test_a_file_name()
```

I would expect when running this that the test would pass but I'm getting a `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error and I can't see why?

Answer (score 0):

When running `unittest.main` your `class` that inherits from `TestCase` gets handed the test method to call. As such you need to allow your class to be handed that argument and pass it on to the parent class `__init__`.

```
from unittest import TestCase, main

class MyTestClass(TestCase):
    # accept arbitrary positional and keyword arguments
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file_name = None
        # pass them on to the parent
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(self):
        self.file_name = 'give this file a name'

        return self.file_name

    def test_a_file_name(self):
        assert self.file_name == 'give this file a name', 'fail'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you noticed, you also don't need to handle instantiation and method calling. `unittest.main()` will do that for you.

In the future, if you ever get an error with arguments, a helpful debugging tip is throwing in an `*args, **kwargs` and `print`ing them to see what is being handed that you're not handling.